# jQuery masonry layout on wordpress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I want to disply 3 or 4 diffrent categorys on the index page (masonry layout).
Each category have different color displayed in the post (like the page shown)
Lets say I want to continue to post with blue box color in the next 5 posts?

Can I use the same loop with conditional statements? Or whats best to do?

http://libra-frisk.com/planeta/

```
        <ul id="customCategory" class="group">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
        <?php 
             if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
               $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
               echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
               the_post_thumbnail('featuredImg');
               echo '</a>';
             }
             ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="info"></div>
    </li>

        <?php endwhile ;?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm mobile so I cant offer much code. But increment with $i then anything > 5 gets the blue version of your content, styles etc.